# Split dataframe column values into windows of size n with overlap and keep date information

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

Current df:

```
Date                 Power
2011-04-18 17:00:01  245.83
2011-04-18 17:00:02  246.02
2011-04-18 17:00:03  245.72
2011-04-18 17:00:04  244.71
2011-04-18 17:00:05  245.93
2011-04-18 17:00:06  243.12
2011-04-18 17:00:07  244.72
2011-04-18 17:00:08  242.44
2011-04-18 17:00:09  246.42
2011-04-18 17:00:10  245.02
...                     ...
```

I want to split the above dataframe into windows of size n=4 (size is variable) and an overlap of o=75. This means that 75 percent of the window will be shared across the previous window and the next. In this example, since 75% of n=4 is 3, I want the window to slide to the right every 1 second (3 seconds will be the common overlap or 75%). I want to create the following df.

```
     date start          date end            power
0    2011-04-18 17:00:01 2011-04-18 17:00:04 [245.83, 246.02, 245.72, 244.71]
1    2011-04-18 17:00:02 2011-04-18 17:00:05 [246.02, 245.72, 244.71, 245.93]
2    2011-04-18 17:00:03 2011-04-18 17:00:06 [245.72, 244.71, 245.93, 243.12]
3    2011-04-18 17:00:04 2011-04-18 17:00:07 [244.71, 245.93, 243.12, 244.72]
4    2011-04-18 17:00:05 2011-04-18 17:00:08 [245.93, 243.12, 244.72, 242.44]
5    2011-04-18 17:00:06 2011-04-18 17:00:09 [243.12, 244.72, 242.44, 246.42]
6    2011-04-18 17:00:07 2011-04-18 17:00:10 [244.72, 242.44, 246.42, 245.02]
...                  ...                 ...                              ...
```

Is there any function in pandas that lets you do this? I searched on the documentation and couldn't find anything that would serve this purpose.

I was able to use the following to turn my dataframe into windows of size n but I have difficulty in making the windows overlapping.

```
def make_row(d):
    return pd.Series({"date_start":d["Date"].min(), "date_end":d["Date"].max(), "power":d["Power"].to_list()})

df.groupby(np.floor(np.linspace(0,len(df)-1,len(df))/n)).apply(make_row).index.astype(int)
```

For reference, the above code results in:

```
     date_start          date_end            power
0    2011-04-18 17:00:01 2011-04-18 17:00:04 [245.83, 246.02, 245.72, 244.71]
1    2011-04-18 17:00:05 2011-04-18 17:00:08 [245.93, 243.12, 244.72, 242.44]
...                  ...                 ...                              ...
```

Comment: will the dates always increase by 1 second?  This would simplify the problem a lot

Answer (score 1):

Give this a go, and if it does what you're expecting I'll flesh out an explanation in an edit.

**setup**

```
n = 4
o = 50
```

**solution**

```
shift = int(n*(1-o/100))
power_shifted = np.stack([df["Power"].shift(x).iloc[::shift] for x in range(0,-n,-1)])
power_lists = pd.DataFrame(power_shifted).transpose().apply(pd.Series.to_list, axis=1).values

result = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "date_start":df["Date"].iloc[::shift],
        "date_end":df["Date"].shift(-n+1).iloc[::shift],
        "power":power_lists,
    }
)
```